# Ubuntu 18 with 2 externals and one internal NIC, I can only acces my server from one external NIC at a time

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet, ip

Internal network : 192.168.10.X
External network : 149.58.60.X

Here are my interface :

eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000

- link/ether 00:15:5d:2f:a4:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.10.100/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global eth0
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe2f:a419/64 scope link
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000

- link/ether 02:00:00:b6:81:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 149.56.60.121/32 scope global eth1
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::ff:fea6:82f0/64 scope link
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000

- link/ether 02:00:00:c5:78:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 149.56.60.122/32 scope global eth2
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::ff:feb5:7497/64 scope link
  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

eth0 and eth1 are the external interface. If only one interface is up (eth1 or eth2), both are working. But when both are up, one one is working, the last one that was up before having both up.

Here is the routing table :

Kernel IP routing table

| Destination | Gateway | Genmask | Flags | Metric | Ref | Use | Iface |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0.0.0 | 51.222.60.254 | 0.0.0.0 | UG | 0 | 0 | 0 | eth2 |
| 0.0.0.0 | 51.222.60.254 | 0.0.0.0 | UG | 0 | 0 | 0 | eth1 |
| 192.168.10.0 | 0.0.0.0 | 255.255.255.0 | U | 0 | 0 | 0 | eth0 |

I try to set different metric for eth2 and eth1, but still not working.

Comment: Using netplan, I set a route table and routing policy to eth1 an eth2 then I can not ping both eth1 and eth2 from external and it works ! table 100 for eth1 and table 200 for eth2.

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  Ubuntu releases have used the *yy* format for *snap* only releases since 2016, and all *snap* releases are intended for server configuration.

Comment: My version is  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Then why not say so, and please correct your title. Ubuntu releases using the *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) are reduced *snap* only systems that provide less functionality than the more traditional *yy.mm* format *deb* based systems. Being precise matters especially when 18 is a different product to 18.04.  Ubuntu has had releases using the *year* only format since 2016.